# What's the best type of steam Trap for Superheated Steam?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, process-engineering, pressure-vessel, steam

Process Engineering Newbie here.
What kind of Steam Traps are best suited for condensate removal in super-heated steam line or manifold?

The super-heated steam is to be supplied to a process reactor and will be at a temperature of around 390 to 420 degree Celsius.
Also the system is supposed to run at different pressures ranging from 1 to 19 barg. I understand that this is not an optimal system. This is a research project and we are developing a proof-of-concept Prototype and is not for deployment in the industry. Hence, the wide range of pressure and high temperature.

I hope experienced engineers in the forum can guide me on how to select a suitable type of steam-trap.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: check this out.  https://www.armstronginternational.com/files/common/technical/859-EN.pdf